# My dropdown menu isn't working properly, where am I going wrong?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am a beginner to web development, and I am trying to make a dropdown menu.

The problem is when I hover on particular element, it consumes more than the expected space.

I want it to appear below the "shop" element. I do not understand where I am going wrong.

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
}

.nav ul {
  /* it edits the list, list-style: none; removes the discs from the list items  */
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 40px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid gold;
}

.nav ul li a {
  /* edits the links- text-decoration: none; removes the underline others are obvious*/
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.nav ul li ul li {
  /* navigation sub-options disappear when not hovered  */
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid greenyellow;
}

.nav ul li:hover ul li {
  /* navigation options appear when hover on elements */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Shop</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Membership</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Activity</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `position: relative` on shop-link and `position: absolute` on dropdown. Then align dropdown with top, left, bottom, transform what would you like.

With `transform` it would look like this:

```
.link {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(100%)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, But I am a beginner, How can I align dropdown to bottom.

Comment: As I said in my answer. Try this css snippet. Set "link" class on the link and "dropdown" class on the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is a bit messy, but to get it working add the following:

```css
/* sub-nav option list */
.nav > ul > li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1px; /* removes border intersection, can't be too large otherwise a gap will remove hover */
  left: -55px;
}
```

`position: absolute` "removes" the element from the container so it is not contained in your parent's border. This will allow us to use the `left`, `right`, `bottom`, `top` CSS properties to position the sub-nav.

`margin-top` is used here to remove the intersection of  `shop` and the `sub-nav`. However, you should be careful increasing this value greater than 1-2px since it will create empty space and hovering on the elements is required for your `sub-nav` to show.

Here is the working snippet:

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
}

.nav ul {
  /* it edits the list, list-style: none; removes the discs from the list items  */
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 40px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid gold;
}

.nav ul li a {
  /* edits the links- text-decoration: none; removes the underline others are obvious*/
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* sub-nav option list */
.nav > ul > li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1px; /* removes border intersection, can't be too large otherwise a gap will remove hover */
  left: -55px;
}

.nav ul li ul li {
  /* navigation sub-options disappear when not hovered  */
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid greenyellow;
}

.nav ul li:hover ul li {
  /* navigation options appear when hover on elements */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Shop</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Membership</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Activity</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Position docs for a better explanation of absolute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: @FictionBelt Also read the comment on `margin-top` if the space between the sub-nav and `shop` is too large it will stop the hover causing the sub-nav to disappear.  Additionally, be weary about what this menu will look like in mobile since we are using absolute positioning. Good day :)

Comment: I've used borders just for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the way you organized these elements. Personally, when I make drop down menus, I use `<button>` for each root of the drop down menu. It makes styling everything much easier.

Then, what I do is I put the main text in an `<h2>` or `<h3>`, and style that how I want the main part of the drop down to look. Everything *inside* of the drop down can be styled using the `<button>` class' settings. Here's how I modified your code to get what I assumed your looking for.

CSS Styling:

```
.nav2 a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.nav2 button {
    margin: 20px 40px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    border: 0px;
    /* change this to the color you want the background of your website to be */
    background-color: white; 
    border: 2px solid gold;
    font-size: 0px;
}

.nav2 button:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 40px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid greenyellow;
    /* change this to the color you want the background of your website to be */
    background-color: white; 
    font-size: 16px;
}

h2 {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

And then the HTML body:

```
<div class="nav2">

    <button>
        <h2><a href="#">Home</a></h2>
    </button>

    <button>
        <h2><a href="#">Shop</a></h2>
            <br><a href="#">Products</a>
            <br><a href="#">Membership</a>
    </button>
    
    <button>
        <h2><a href="#">Blog</a></h2>
    </button>
    
    <button>
        <h2><a href="#">News</a></h2>
    </button>
    
    <button>
        <h2><a href="#">Activity</a></h2>
    </button>
    
        <button>
        <h2><a href="#">Contact Us</a></h2>
    </button>
    
</div>
```

The end result looked like this
[image: Stylized Drop down Menus]

I hope my response was helpful!!

Comment: Nothin to be sorry for! I just hope I was able to help with the issue. The responses from Cela and Maroz also seem like they work beautifully! Just use whatever is easiest for you to implement and understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Here You have:

```css
.nav{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.nav ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav ul li{
    background-color: gold;
    border: 1px solid gold;
    color: #FFF;
}
.nav ul li:hover{ 
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: gold; 
}
.nav ul li a{
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Verdana;
}
.nav ul li ul {
    /* navigation sub-options disappear when not hovered  */
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 2px solid greenyellow;
}
.nav ul li:hover ul {
    /* navigation options appear when hover on elements */
    display: flex;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Shop</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Membership</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Activity</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact US</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```